# Helm lookup weird behavior in the beginning of a yaml

Tags: if-statement, kubernetes-helm, lookup

I have a yaml file for generating a k8s secret:

```
{{- $secret_name := printf "%s-%s" .Values.app.secret.name  .Values.stage -}}
{{- if not (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace $secret_name).data }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ $secret_name }}
data:
{{- range .Values.app.secret.data }}
  {{ .key }}: {{ .value }}
{{- end}}
{{- end }}
```

The secret that is being looked up already exists in current namespace. But the lookup doesn't seen to find it.

I am checking against a running k8s cluster via
`helm install -dry-run`
or
`helm template --validate --debug`

BTW the *$service_name* variable is being generated correctly

If I add another field somewhere like this:

```
{{- $secret_name := printf "%s-%s" .Values.app.secret.name  .Values.stage -}}
{{- if not (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace $secret_name).data }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ $secret_name }}
  name1: {{ (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace $secret_name).data }}
data:
{{- range .Values.app.secret.data }}
  {{ .key }}: {{ .value }}
{{- end}}
{{- end }}
```

the data is being returned as expected. But if I put the same line in the beginning of the file the data is not being returned.

```
{{- $secret_name := printf "%s-%s" .Values.app.secret.name  .Values.stage -}}
name1: {{ (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace $secret_name).data }}
{{- if not (lookup "v1" "Secret" .Release.Namespace $secret_name).data }}
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: {{ $secret_name }}
data:
{{- range .Values.app.secret.data }}
  {{ .key }}: {{ .value }}
{{- end}}
{{- end }}
```

I cannot understand what is going on )))

Comment: (I probably wouldn't try to use `lookup` to conditionally create objects only if they don't exist.  For example, I might expect that running `helm upgrade` will actually delete the Secret on alternating runs, if it didn't exist during the initial `helm install`.)

Comment: You are probably right about suggesting not to use `lookup` in this case, I have already separated the objects that are common to my several deployment. But I would like to understand what is going on anyway.

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation, —-dry-run do not actually connect to a live cluster. One should use —-dry-run=“server” to do it.